# Linear time complexity ranking algorithm when the orders are precomputed

Tags: algorithm, r, correlation, missing-data

I am trying to write an efficient ranking algorithm in C++ but I will present my case in R as it is far easier to understand this way.

```
> samples_x <- c(4, 10, 9, 2, NA, 3, 7, 1, NA, 8)
> samples_y <- c(5, 7, 9, NA, 1, 4, NA, 8, 2, 10)
> orders_x <- order(samples_x)
> orders_y <- order(samples_y)
> cbind(samples_x, orders_x, samples_y, orders_y)
      samples_x orders_x samples_y orders_y
 [1,]         4        8         5        5
 [2,]        10        4         7        9
 [3,]         9        6         9        6
 [4,]         2        1        NA        1
 [5,]        NA        7         1        2
 [6,]         3       10         4        8
 [7,]         7        3        NA        3
 [8,]         1        2         8       10
 [9,]        NA        5         2        4
[10,]         8        9        10        7
```

Suppose the above is already precomputed. Performing a simple ranking on each of the sample sets takes linear time complexity (the result is much like the `rank` function):

```
> ranks_x <- rep(0, length(samples_x))
> for (i in 1:length(samples_x)) ranks_x[orders_x[i]] <- i
```

For a work project I am working on, it would be useful for me to emulate the following behaviour in linear time complexity:

```
> cc <- complete.cases(samples_x, samples_y)
> ranks_x <- rank(samples_x[cc])
> ranks_y <- rank(samples_y[cc])
```

The `complete.cases` function, when given n sets of the same length, returns the indices for which none of the sets contain NAs. The `order` function returns the permutation of indices corresponding to the sorted sample set. The `rank` function returns the ranks of the sample set.

How to do this? Let me know if I have provided sufficient information as to the problem in question.

More specifically, I am trying to build a correlation matrix based on Spearman's rank sum correlation coefficient test in a way such that NAs are handled properly. The presence of NAs requires that the rankings be calculated for every pairwise sample set (`s n^2 log n`); I am trying to avoid that by calculating the orders once for every sample set (`s n log n`) and use a linear complexity for every pairwise comparison. Is this even doable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the C++ tag (or a C++ question) but perhaps someone with R and C++ expertise may be able to help.

Comment: Your use of R may make things easier for *you* to understand, but makes it completely opaque to anybody who doesn't know R.

Comment: I have edited my main thread so as to describe the R functions I've presented. Hopefully, one may now treat the R code as pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, when you work out the rank correlation of two arrays, you want to delete from both arrays elements in positions where either has NA.

You have

for (i in 1:length(samples_x)) ranks_x[orders_x[i]] <- i

Could you change this to something like

```
wp <- 0;
for (i in 1:length(samples_x)) {
if ((samples_x[orders_x[i]] == NA) ||
 (samples_y[orders_x[i]] == NA))
 {
   ranks_x[orders_x[i]] <- NA;
 }
 else
 {
   ranks_x[orders_x[i]] <- wp++;
 }
}
```

Then you could either go along later and compress out the NAs, or hope the correlation subroutine just ignores them.

Comment: I've spent hours on trying to figure out how to do this but to no avail! Thank you so much, it works perfectly! I changed the pseudocode to R code (so as to be compliant with the topic).